# Why am I getting Chrome Native Messaging "Specified native messaging host not found."?

Tags: javascript, json, windows, google-chrome, chrome-native-messaging

I have been working on this for a while now, I can't figure this out. I've read the [Chrome Native Messaging docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging), but I keep getting a "Specified native messaging host not found." error from the extension.

Manifest pointed by registry:

```
{
  "name": "com.fordcars.chromekeys",
  "description": "ChromeKeys description",
  "path": "C:\Users\fordcars\Desktop\Development\ChromeKeys\Debug\ChromeKeys.exe",
    "type": "stdio",
    "allowed_origins": [
     "chrome-extension://pdkakljppghagmaoijbpicogfdbodpbc"
     ]
}
```

Extension script:

```
// Event page

var nativeName = "com.fordcars.chromekeys";

var nativePort = chrome.runtime.connectNative(nativeName);

function nativeDataReceived(data)
{
    // Not used
}

function nativeDisconnected()
{
    console.log("Native program disconnected. Error: " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
}

nativePort.onMessage.addListener(nativeDataReceived);
nativePort.onDisconnect.addListener(nativeDisconnected);
```

Keep in mind I get the error as soon as I connectNative(). I have "nativeMessaging" permission in my extension manifest.

Registry:

```
Subkey: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.fordcars.chromekeys

Value name: (Default)

Value: C:\Users\fordcars\Desktop\Development\ChromeKeys\Debug\nativeManifest.json
```

**Debugging:**
I have done some debugging and have found that if I change my connectNative nativeName from *com.fordcars.chromekeys* to anything else, I *still* get the same error, so it is either *not finding the registry key* or/and *I don't have a good manifest.json*.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you _really_ should read the documentation again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A backslash is an escape character in JSON. You have to use two backslashes as a path separator in your manifest:

```js
// BAD:
"path": "C:\Users\fordcars\Desktop\Development\ChromeKeys\Debug\ChromeKeys.exe",
// GOOD:
"path": "C:\\Users\\fordcars\\Desktop\\Development\\ChromeKeys\\Debug\\ChromeKeys.exe",
```

I strongly recommend to learn how to debug as described in [Debugging native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-debugging), because if you do that, then you would have seen a more detailed error message:

> Found manifest, but not the binary for native messaging host com.fordcars.chromekeys. Host path specified in the manifest: C:UsersordcarsDesktopDevelopmentChromeKeysDebugChromeKeys.exe

Even without looking at the error log, if you had followed the bullet points at the error message, you could have noticed the difference between the [sample manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-host) and yours (namely the misspelled backslashes).

Comment: Yeah I only just got that from a JSON validator, but will definitely check out the output from Chrome logs

Comment: If anybody comes across this while trying to troubleshoot (Chromium-based) *Edge* issues, be aware that you do *not* get the detailed error message on the console with `--enable-logging`.  I managed to guess why my host wasn't "found" (`allowed_origins` was missing a trailing slash) but those debugging instructions did not help.